# What is _ (single underscore) in Perl without $ or @?

Tags: perl

I have some code like this:

```
if (!-d _ || !-o _ || ($vncUserDirUnderTmp && ($mode & 0777) != 0700)) {
    raise Exception("$prog: Wrong type or access mode of $vncUserDir.\n")
}
```

I could find information about `@_` and `$_` in Perl but not about `_` alone.
What does it mean in `-d _` and `-o _` here?

Comment: `!-d` tests that the file is not a directory. `-o` check the file ownership

Comment: For operators that take a file handle, you can pass the name of a glob. `-d _` is short for `-d *_` just like `print STDOUT ...` is short for `print *STDOUT ...`

Comment: Does your code actually read "if (...): raise Exception(...)"? Does that syntax come from some module?

Comment: @Matthias Yes, it is. I didn't write it myself, it is a part of TightVNC source code. Is there any problem there?

Comment: @Kim The TightVNC source code doesn't contain that. tightvnc-1.3.10_unixsrc.tar.bz2's vncserver contains `if (!-d _ || !-o _ || ($vncUserDirUnderTmp && ($mode & 0777) != 0700)) {
    die "$prog: Wrong type or access mode of $vncUserDir.\n";
}`. What you put in your question looks like a strange mix of Perl and Python.

Comment: @hvd Exactly^^ I was just curious about the syntax, because I never saw perl code written like that. I thought maybe they added new syntax with 5.2x (but did not find it in a delta), or you are using some module. Since no one pointed out the syntax error, I thought it might be valid with some version of perl or some module.

Comment: Ah...That's my mistake. I had tried to convert Perl code to Python. I edited the code. I'm sorry .

Answer (score 59):

When used with a [filetest (-X)](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) operator the `stat` structure of the previous file test is used

> If any of the file tests (or either the `stat` or `lstat` operator) is given the special filehandle consisting of a solitary underline, then the `stat` structure of the previous file test (or `stat` operator) is used, saving a system call.
>   ...
>   Example:
>
> ```
> stat($filename);  
> print "Readable\n" if -r _;  
> print "Writable\n" if -w _;
> ...
> ```

So in your example `!-d _` tests whether the file last `stat`-ed isn't a directory.

**Update**

The unusual `_` is really a typeglob `*_` but with operators expecting a filehandle the `*` may be omitted, like `<*STDIN>` may be written as `<STDIN>`.  It is found in the symbol table

```
print *{$main::{_}}{IO}, "\n";   # -->  IO::Handle=IO(0x2311970)
```

In a one-liner the `*_` gets set up only after calls to `stat` and `_` are made.

Comment: But what is the initial value of that stat cache? I notice that it contains something even if there was no previous stat call. Is it just random garbage?

Comment: @AnT An interesting point. I'd guess that it could refer to the script itself, but I can't get anything out of it. Among other attempts, I print all filetests (like `-s _`), before anything else in the script, and they're all `undef`.  So I can't confirm that the `stat` cache is set (while the handle itself, `*_`, is).

Answer (score 44):

When you call one of the file test operators (`-f`, `-d`, `-s`, etc) Perl actually makes a call to the operating system's `stat` function. The `stat` function returns a structure full of all sorts of interesting information about the file in question, but each of the file test operators only looks at one of the fields from that structure (is it a file? is it a directory? how big is it?)

It's common that you might want to know more that one piece of information about a file (is it a file? can I read it? can I execute it?) The naive way to write that is:

```
if (-f $file and -r $file and -x $file)
```

But that makes three calls to `stat` - with each one of them only looking at one of the fields from the structure. To mitigate that, Perl is clever and caches the results of the most recent call to `stat`. It is cached against the special filehandle `_`. So a more efficient way to write the same code is:

```
if (-f $file and -r _ and -x _)
```

That only makes one call to `stat`.

Since Perl 5.10, you can also use "stacked file tests" and write this code as:

```
if (-x -r -f $file) # Note reversed order of operators
```

**Update:** [perldoc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html#-X-FILEHANDLE) says this about stacked file operators.

> As of Perl 5.10.0, as a form of purely syntactic sugar, you can
>   stack file test operators, in a way that `-f -w -x $file` is
>   equivalent to`"-x $file && -w _ && -f _`. (This is only fancy
>   syntax: if you use the return value of `-f $file` as an argument
>   to another filetest operator, no special magic will happen.)

Comment: They're actually queued (executed left to right), right?

Comment: I learned something new today! (Didn't know about stackable file tests.)